# web server Load testing tool

Tags: load, load-testing

Can you suggest a software tool (with GPLv license) to perform load testing for a Web server?

Answer (score 30):

Curl will allow you to run through a sequence of URL quite easily. i.e.

```
curl -s "http://google.com?[1-1000]"
```

This will make 1000 calls to google i.e.

```
http://google.com?1  
http://google.com?2
etc...
```

You can then add these calls to a script and run them consecutively as background jobs. There's a full explanation of this http://servermonitoringhq.com/blog/how_to_quickly_stress_test_a_web_server

Answer (score 12):

1. [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/) is best I have used so far. You can create actual usage pattern.
2. [apache benchmark](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) is easiest to use and comes along with apache. Simpler to use,but is not flexible in terms of urls to hit for testing and creating more realistic load patterns.

Comment: Thanks alot for the tsung recommendation, able to record a session and replay , been looking for something like this! Awesome tool!

Answer (score 9):

Try one of:

- httperf (http://code.google.com/p/httperf/)
- ab (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html)

Answer (score 6):

If you need to do some performance/load testing also to web pages/apps, try Apache JMeter http://jmeter.apache.org/

Comment: Jmeter is the best solution I think if you need to create a custom graph of your results.

Answer (score 2):

You can give a try to wbox by running `apt-get install wbox`

Then scroll down at `hping.org/wbox/` for examples.

comprehensive list at [Speed Tools](https://developers.google.com/speed/tools)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using the "headless" [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (which is related to Selenium WebDriver) or using the Selenium HTMLUnitDriver.  Wrap the load tests in a JUnit class.  Fork the tests multi-threaded using either Maven Surefire or Gradle (with a filtering test task using maxParallelForks).  Gradle or Maven will create a JUnit report (from a CSS transformation) that shows each test and the time each one took.

If you are using Windows, you can can use my .bat [scripts to start a Grid Node and Hub](https://github.com/djangofan/WebDriverTestingTemplate)  in order to run parallel, using multiple computers to supply the load..

Answer (score 2):

If you have the production workload, then you could use [tcpcopy](https://github.com/wangbin579/tcpcopy) to copy it to the test system. This kind of testing is more effective and real.

Answer (score 0):

Also look at re purposing Selenium WebDriver functional scripts in a Headless browser environment where you can run multiple instances. This approach has become popular with the availability of VMs from the Cloud.