# Tomcat Current thread count

Tags: apache2, tomcat7

Tomcat and appache2 are connected through AJP. I have these configurations for tomcat and apache:

```
<Connector port="8009" protocol="AJP/1.3"
           URIEncoding="UTF-8"
           redirectPort="8443"
           connectionTimeout="20000"
           maxThreads="512" />


<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    ServerLimit        1024
    MaxClients          512
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

When I go to tomcat manager, I see :

```
"ajp-bio-8009"
Max threads: 512 Current thread count: 256 Current thread busy: 231
```

The current thread busy sometimes reaches 256. Why isn't the current thread count set to 512?

Answer (score 2):

The current thread is dynamically managed by apache.

from worker.c in apache's source code:
thread is started as needed.  following is the main flow to start worker thread.

```
static int worker_run(apr_pool_t *_pconf, apr_pool_t *plog, server_rec *s)
  startup_children(remaining_children_to_start);  //server/mpm/worker/worker.c
     if (make_child(ap_server_conf, i) < 0) {     //server/mpm/worker/worker.c
       child_main(slot);                          //server/mpm/worker/worker.c
         rv = apr_thread_create(&start_thread_id, thread_attr, start_threads
         rv = apr_thread_create(&threads[i], thread_attr, worker_thread, my_info, pchild);
```

And when idle thread > max_spare_threads, apache will try to reduce the spare thread by kill child process/thread to reduce the idle threads count.

```
if (idle_thread_count > max_spare_threads) {
    /* Kill off one child */
    ap_worker_pod_signal(pod, TRUE);
    retained->idle_spawn_rate = 1;
}
```

internally apache manage these child process, and using signal to communicate with child process to adjust threads as needed.
all threads are managed in `ap_scoreboard_image->servers[i][j];`

apache will monitor the thread count, and using socket send out to let infoCollector know.
roughly by following code (unrelated line were deleted)

```
./httpd/modules/cluster/mod_heartbeat.c
    for (i = 0; i < ctx->server_limit; i++) {
         ....
            for (j = 0; j < ctx->thread_limit; j++) {
                ws = &ap_scoreboard_image->servers[i][j];
                if (res == SERVER_READY && ps->generation == mpm_generation) {
                    ready++;
                }
            }
        }

    len = apr_snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "v=%u&ready=%u&busy=%u", MSG_VERSION, ready, busy);
    ...
    rv = apr_socket_sendto(sock, ctx->mcast_addr, 0, buf, &len);
```

**In Tomcat:**
these thread info are received by:
./tomcat/java/org/apache/catalina/ha/backend/CollectedInfo.java
and displayed by:
/Users/twer/lab/tomcat/java/org/apache/catalina/manager/StatusTransformer.java

```
writer.write(" currentThreadCount=\"" + mBeanServer.getAttribute(tpName, "currentThreadCount") + "\"");
```

most of the code show here are main flow, unrelated line are deleted. download the source to find out more.
download apache src: http://www.apache.org/dist/httpd/?C=S;O=A
download tomcat src: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but this doesn't answer my question.
I'm scaling up my server. I used to have max threads = 128, and most of them were busy. I changed it to max threads = 256. With this number, I was having 200 threads busy. Now I'm getting more hits. I guess that 400 threads should be busy, so I doubled the number of max threads to 512. But the server is only serving a max of 256 threads at a time.
So my question is: What should I do to have my server use more threads?

Comment: try using some web load test tool , let the server receive more request, to see if it can up to 512. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139953/web-server-load-testing-tool